# Role of "be" in "Staff may request that a check be issued instead."

Tags: infinitives, subjunctives

> Staff may request that a check **be** issued instead.

I have two questions about this sentence.

First question:

I am not sure why "be" is used here.
Can anyone explain it, please?

Second question:

I made the following sentences to express the same meaning.
Are they correct?

1. Staff may request a check instead.
2. Staff may request a check to be issued instead.
3. Staff may request to issue a check instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The construction *{ form of to be } + { past participle form of verb }* is the [passive voice](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/passive.htm).  It is a way of expressing an action without mentioning a specific person or category of people involved in the action, which can be used to be polite or businesslike, or to deflect blame.

*Be* is used instead of *is* because the phrase *that a check be issued instead* is in the subjunctive mood.  The subjunctive mood is confusing but it can appear after a number of verbs and *request* is one of those.

Your alternate sentences replace the *that* clause with a noun or verbal as an object of request, which is fine and 100% correct.  The subjunctive mood can be used to imply politeness, business politeness, or formality, and this is lost when you "convert" the clause to a noun, though.

Comment: Thanks for your time. Your answer really helped me understand this sentence.